# how to refresh the div content without the page reloads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the modal with form on click of save it saves in the temporary page and the modal has to close the values should get displayed in the div content.now it is working fine but when the page reloads the content is displaying.i don't want to reload the page

html code:

```
<div class="content">

  <?php if($load_data): ?>

    <?php foreach($load_data as $data): ?>
      <div class="row modal_bg">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <span class="jd_name"><?php echo $data->first_name; ?></span>
          <span class="jd_name" ><?php echo $data->last_name; ?></span>
          <p class="loc"><?php echo $data->location; ?></p>
        </div>

      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

ajax code:

```
jQuery.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "page/datapage/",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(res) 
      {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        console.log(res);
        if(res)
        {

          url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>page/datapage/<?php echo $per->id;  ?>";

        }
      },
    error: function(errResponse) 
      {
        console.log(errResponse);
      }
  });
```

how to solve this issue ,without page reload i want to display the content.can anyone suggest me how to do.

Comment: research `.html()`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Exactly.

Comment: If this is about data updating from a source, you could take a look at RxJS and use `Subscribers`.

Comment: You should use .html() tag

Comment: @ ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs research.html where should i place this code

Comment: 1. what is `url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>page/datapage/<?php echo $per->id;  ?>";` supposed to be? 2. If you submit a form and you don't want the page to reload you have to suppress the standard submission: `e.preventDefault`

Comment: @lakshmipriya inside your success callback e.g. `$('#target-div').html(res)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `html()`;

```
success: function(res) 
      {
$('#yourTargetId').html(res);
```

Comment: what is out put of console.log(res);

Comment: show me this page <?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "page/datapage/"

Comment: What Rahul said here is correct. Note that the $('#yourTargetId').html(res); prints out every html content from the file that is spefified in the AJAX url. So if you need it show something specific, all you need is to construct that in that file and it will be loaded into the targeted element on success.